# Select distinct in week and distinct overall per week

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have an example on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a43f3/1). What I am trying to do is divide the overall `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` by the weekly `COUNT(DISTINCT ID)`. For example if I have the following conceptual setup of what the `result` should be.

```
year week id_set       overall_distinct   week_distinct  result
2016   1  A,A,A,B,B,C    0                   3            0
2016   2  A,B,C,C,D      1                   4           .25
2016   3  A,B,C,E,F      2                   5           .4
```

The table linked to on sql fiddle has the following schema. Also, in reality I do have multiple values for 'year'.

```
CREATE TABLE all_ids
    ([year] int, [week] int, [id] varchar(57))
;
INSERT INTO all_ids
    ([year], [week], [id])
VALUES
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'B'),
    (2016, 1, 'B'),
    (2016, 1, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'A'),
    (2016, 2, 'B'),
    (2016, 2, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'D'),
    (2016, 3, 'A'),
    (2016, 3, 'B'),
    (2016, 3, 'C'),
    (2016, 3, 'E'),
    (2016, 3, 'F')
;
```

## Edit

I apologize for the confusion. The above table was just a conceptual example of the result. The actual result only needs to look like the following.

```
year week  overall_distinct   week_distinct  result
2016   1     0                   3            0
2016   2     1                   4           .25
2016   3     2                   5           .4
```

there is no need to include `id_set`

Comment: How are you calculating `overall_distinct`?

Comment: `overall_distinct` are the values that are distinct across all weeks, not just week 1. So in week 1. `overall_distinct` is `0` because `A,A,A,B,B,C` appear in other weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `dense_rank` and `max() over ()` to simulate `count (distinct ...)` with window functions. You could try to do it with another subquery

```
select
    year, week
    , id_set = stuff((
        select
            ',' + a.id
        from
            all_ids a
        where
            a.year = t.year
            and a.week = t.week
        order by a.id
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
    , overall_distinct = count(case when cnt = 1 then 1 end)
    , week_distinct = count(distinct id)
    , result = cast(count(case when cnt = 1 then 1 end) * 1.0 / count(distinct id) as decimal(10, 2))
from (
    select
        year, week, id, cnt = max(dr) over (partition by id)
    from (
        select 
            *, dr = dense_rank() over (partition by id order by year, week)
        From 
            all_ids
    ) t
) t
group by year, week
```

Output

```
year    week    id_set         overall_distinct    week_distinct   result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016    1       A,A,A,B,B,C    0                   3               0.00
2016    2       A,B,C,C,D      1                   4               0.25
2016    3       A,B,C,E,F      2                   5               0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way, probably not the best one:

```
;with weekly as 
(
    select year, week, count(distinct id) nr 
    from all_ids 
    group by year, week
),
overall as
(
    select a.week, count(distinct a.id) nr 
    from all_ids a 
    where a.id not in (select id from all_ids where week <> a.week and id = a.id ) 
    group by week 

)
select distinct a.year
     , a.week
     , stuff((select ', ' + id 
              from all_ids
              where year = a.year and week = a.week
              for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') ids
     , w.Nr weeklyDistinct
     , isnull(t.Nr, 0) overallDistinct
from all_ids a join weekly w on a.year = w.year and a.week = w.week
               left join overall t on t.week = a.week
```

Comment: Though I selected the above answer also like this code because it is more general and I will have to port this to `exasol`. One question I have is, how do I get the result? `isnull(t.Nr, 0) / w.Nr` results in all zeros for me on sql fiddle. What would you suggest?

Comment: `CAST(isnull(t.Nr, 0)AS FLOAT) / CAST(w.Nr AS FLOAT)` did the trick

Comment: Yep. This would also do: `cast(isnull(t.Nr, 0) * 1.0 / w.Nr as float)`

Comment: I am a little confused on this line `select id from all_ids where week <> a.week and id = a.id` could you explain what the purpose of this outer join is?

Comment: Yes, to find all distinct `IDs` across all weeks. 
For each week, check if the `IDs` for that week appear anywhere else, besides the current week itself (hence the condition `week <> a.week`) and if so, don't count them (because you only need distinct ones), otherwise do.

Answer (score 1):

One statement count only

```
declare @t table (y int, w int, id varchar(57));
INSERT @t (y, w, id)
VALUES
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'A'),
    (2016, 1, 'B'),
    (2016, 1, 'B'),
    (2016, 1, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'A'),
    (2016, 2, 'B'),
    (2016, 2, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'C'),
    (2016, 2, 'D'),
    (2016, 3, 'A'),
    (2016, 3, 'B'),
    (2016, 3, 'C'),
    (2016, 3, 'E'),
    (2016, 3, 'F');

select t1.w, count(distinct t1.id) as wk
     , (count(distinct t1.id) - count(distinct t2.id)) as [all]
     , (cast(1 as smallmoney) - cast(count(distinct t2.id) as smallmoney)  / count(distinct t1.id)) as [frac]
from @t t1
left join @t t2 
  on t2.id = t1.id 
 and t2.w <> t1.w 
group by t1.w
order by t1.w;
```

Comment: does this handle multiple years?

Comment: @Alex It could with minor changes.